# Summing visible cells in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to sum a set of visible cells in a data sheet using the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(C2:C6,ROW(C2:C6)-MIN(ROW(C2:C6)),,1,1))*(A2:A6="peter")*(B2:B6=201104))
```

due to the fact of my dashboard having a huge back end dataset (170k), the dashboard freezes when I use this formula (I have to use this on every table I want to display on the front end).

Is there a way to optimize this?  Or perhaps a faster method using index and match.

Comment: Simple Formulas like CountA and Countif also freeze excel if you have dataset like 170K. So Index/Match definitely wont give you any different results. My Suggestion

Use VBA and then show a customized Userform with progressbar so that Excel doesn't give you the "Hung Up" feel. This will however in no way decrease the speed until and unless you use array to perform your calculations

Comment: I used the following method...its not fast...but its definitely faster than using offset.  I first copied the filtered data to another sheet.  I defined pivot tables and in the macros, updated the pivot tabes as and when a filter was done.

Comment: I thought you wanted an automated method :) If you are comfortable with the manual method then it's kool :)

Comment: Its automated....i used "Worksheets("Summary").PivotTables("summary_state").PivotCache.Refresh"in the macro to automatically update the pivot :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works perfectly if you copy the data to another sheet.  Enable a new pivot table with all columns.  Thus, when the data is filtered in the data sheet, the copied sheet will contain only the filtered values.

The pivot table will now obtain only the copied data (i.e., filtered data).  Once this is complete, you will need to add a line of code in vba :

```
worksheets("Summary").pivottables("summary_view").pivotcache.refresh
```

and it automatically updates the pivot table.  Hence, when you filter the data in the sheet using a listbox, the pivot automatically gets updated